# Exclude BBCode tags from character count?

Tags: count, bbcode

I'm currently using jBBCodes for my forum (custom made) and I have a character limit of 15k however my issue is that the character count check will also count the bbcode tags e.g [b]Hey![/b] would count as 11 when it should count as 4.

The count check;

```
    if (strlen($message)<5 || strlen($message)>15000) {
    die("<div style='text-align:center;' class='error'>The character limit is 5 to 15,000, your post was ".number_format(strlen($message))." character(s).</div><br>");
    }
```

I'm wondering how can I exclude BBCodes I don't want to exclude [ ] people do use it for other things on top of that anyone can just [message] so that's out of the question is there any possible way to do this without having to check for each tag in full?

Comment: Look up regex. you have a fun day ahead of you.

Comment: Please try my library for parsing shortcodes and BBCodes: github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . In this example you'll just need to register default shortcode that only returns content and count length of the string after processing. If you need any help, let me know through issues on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly simple task for regular expressions.

Basically, if you need the length of a string not including BBCodes, then use this token: `strlen(preg_replace('~\[(codes|to|match)](.*?)\[/\1]~g', '$2', $message))`